# One of Multiple DS18B20 sensor showing wrong temperature

Tags: arduino, esp8266, arduino-c++

I have a 4 sensors and one of my sensor always showing wrong temperature. This is not problem with sensor but this is problem with code because I checked it.

```
void getTemperature() {
  float tempC;
  float tempC3;
  float tempC2;
  float tempC4;
  do {
    DS18B20.requestTemperatures(); 
    tempC = DS18B20.getTempCByIndex(0);
    dtostrf(tempC, 2, 2, temperatureCString);
    tempC3 = DS18B20.getTempFByIndex(1);
    dtostrf(tempC3, 3, 2, temperatureCString3);
    tempC2 = DS18B20.getTempCByIndex(2);
    dtostrf(tempC2, 4, 2, temperatureCString2);
    tempC4 = DS18B20.getTempCByIndex(3);
    dtostrf(tempC4, 5, 2, temperatureCString4);
    delay(100);
  } while (tempC == 85.0 || tempC == (-127.0));
}
```

Sending data.

```
if (c == '\n' && blank_line) {
        getTemperature();
        client.println("HTTP/1.1 200 OK");
        client.println("Content-Type: application/json");
        client.println("Connection: close");
        client.println();
        // your actual web page that displays temperature
        client.print("[");
        client.print(temperatureCString);
         client.print(",");
         client.print(temperatureCString2);
         client.print(",");
         client.print(temperatureCString3);
         client.print(",");
         client.print(temperatureCString4);
         client.print("]");

        break;
    }
    if (c == '\n') {
      // when starts reading a new line
      blank_line = true;
    }
    else if (c != '\r') {
      // when finds a character on the current line
      blank_line = false;
    }
  }
}  
// closing the client connection
delay(1);
client.stop();
Serial.println("Client disconnected.");
  }
```

Here is what I see: https://screenshots.firefox.com/IStMqTgJTI2lmLxz/192.168.0.242
When I left only one sensor i see something like this:
https://screenshots.firefox.com/sSXSYmcQbDLF9mUj/192.168.0.242
Always 3rd (id 2) sensor showing wrong temperature even when he is not there. 
Some of you have any idea?

Comment: Hard to tell without seeing the whole code. Also, have you tried swapping the sensors to rule out the faulty hardware?

Comment: If it is on a breadboard then move it to a new spot. Your contacts on that spot may have some sort of residue causing inaccurate readings. Also where is this dtostrf. You should also add pictures using the Image button or just put the data directly so we do not have to click on other links when not needed.